# Correct installation file my version

Tags: linux, rpm

I am using the following Linux version.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
```

Which file should I download and install from this page?

http://mysql.oss.eznetsols.org/Downloads/MySQL-Proxy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever possible, it is typically a better idea to install packages using your distributions package manager than to download and compile them yourself. You are in luck, the package `mysql-proxy` is available through EPEL. EPEL is a community driven project to extend the available packages for RedHat/CentOS, while remaining compatible with the base distro.

Since EPEL may have newer versions of packages than what RedHat ships, I tend to avoid using it directly. However, if you don't have the infrastructure to support a partial local mirror, we can work around it. What I would recommend is installing the EPEL repository, set it disabled, and only enable it for specific packages. This will prevent updates from pulling in packages from EPEL that you didn't necessarily want.

One caveat, lies with the versions of packages that are available. Since RedHat is attempting to keep all the packages within their repo compatible, and making sure they are supportable, sometimes the versions end up being a little older. Usually this is fine because

1. They will backport security patches
2. Most of the time the latest and greatest features aren't actually needed

EPEL can often end up in the same boat and should be treated accordingly. If you really need a newer version than is available, then you will of course need to go with other sources. Perhaps [rpmforge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge) or compile from source. Before going outside the  normal repos, I would take a good hard look at the feature sets and determine if the deviation really is useful or necessary.

To install EPEL (shamelessly pasting from the official [Instructions](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F))

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/`uname -i`/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'
```

Disable EPEL by default

```
sed -i '' -e's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Install mysql-proxy from EPEL

```
yum install --enablerepo=epel mysql-proxy
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems this process does not install the latest version. The older version was installed #mysql-proxy-0.5.1-2.el5

Comment: That's true, you received the newest version available on EPEL. Added some explanation on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Check your architecture with `uname -a` to see if you're on a 64-bit system or a 32-bit system.

If 64-bit (x86_64), download:  mysql-proxy-0.8.1-linux-rhel5-x86-64bit.tar.gz

If 32-bit (i386), download:  mysql-proxy-0.8.1-linux-rhel5-x86-32bit.tar.gz

Comment: I have installed this mysql-proxy-0.8.1-linux-glibc2.3-x86-64bit.tar.gz Is it oK?